# Error while running webapplication with google appengine

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-plugin-eclipse

I created a small web application.if i deployed its work but if try to run application it show
the port 8888 appears to be in use(perhaps by another lanch),do you still to contine with this lanch? i clicked yes 
but show the error 
Could not open the requested socket: Address already in use: bind
Try overriding --address and/or --port.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is what it is stating.

You are facing this issue because of the following:

- Either the port 8888 is in use by some other application and not previous launch. This is less likely.
- This condition is more likely and it is because you have already launched the application once i.e. via the Run as Web Application. And it is still running. In your Eclipse, visit the Window-> Show View -> Console. And in the Console window, you will find one or more previous instances running. Please stop that.[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are some instances where the solution suggested by Romin will not work because the option to stop the process does not present itself in the console.

In these cases, you can probably find out which process ID is using the port and then kill that process.

For example, on a mac, this worked for me:

```
    >lsof -i tcp:8888
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    25866 alexryan   60u  IPv6 0x96e9c26778f105e1      0t0  TCP localhost:ddi-tcp-1 (LISTEN)
    >kill 25866
    >lsof -i tcp:8888
    >
```

Answer (score 0):

The port number 8888 is in use means that port already been activated. do one thing go to servicees option of control panel set the server start option from automatic to manual. Then your apps will get run. else you can stop the server from your eclipse env stop option.